# Is a semicolon the right punctuation in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, semicolons

This is for a cover letter. Please help!

"I speak Spanish; I have a working familiarity with French and I am currently teaching myself Arabic."

Answer (score 4):

I would itemize it as a list, sorted by level of familiarity (descending).

> I am fluent in Spanish, I have a working knowledge of French, and I am currently teaching myself Arabic

---

In your original sentence, there are three distinct clauses:

- I speak Spanish
- I have a working familiarity with French
- I am currently teaching myself Arabic

It is awkward to join the last two with a conjunction, then use a semi-colon to tack that conjoined sentence onto the first one. Strictly speaking it is grammatically correct, but it is inconsistent and awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of semicolon: A punctuation mark indicating a pause, typically between two main clauses, that is more pronounced than that indicated by a comma.
Source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com

There's nothing incorrect about the semicolon in your example, although a period may 'appear' better.

"I speak Spanish. I have a working familiarity with French and (I) am currently teaching myself Arabic."

Note: My recommendation splits the sentence based on two aspects: 1. Fluency in Spanish. 2. Familiarity and efforts to learn another.

Comment: Grammatically, this is fine. But mfoy_ correctly judges that the independent clauses are so closely parallel that one sentence, using no more than commas to separate them, is the better format. He further gives a good reason for putting the clauses in a certain order.

Comment: Good. But what do we think about the repetition of "I" in the answer? I'd think  "I am fluent in Spanish, have a working knowledge of French, and am currently teaching myself Arabic" would look better. My recommendation splits the sentence based on two aspects: 1. Fluency in Spanish. 2. Familiarity and efforts to learn another.

Comment: Now _you_'ve added a good reason for your choice. The parallelism still applies, though; I'd go with a,b,c rather than a; b,c (without other context). As regards the I-deletions – perhaps very slightly preferable (but this _is_ a formal register).

Comment: It's for the very same reason that I prefer breaking the sentence down. "I am fluent in Spanish. I have a working knowledge of French, and (I) am currently teaching myself Arabic." would sound better, I believe. Thanks for your feedback :-)

Comment: While your way is certainly not in any way wrong, has merit and is fine for you to choose, and while I'd choose it myself in some follow-on contexts, it may be instructive to note the numbers of votes given for the choices.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin Ashworth. We live in a world of choices, don't we?

Comment: I think what's slightly disconcerting me is that your version hints at 'but I only' whereas mfoy_'s hints at 'and what's more, ...'.

Comment: Good point, all so subtle...